# Apps of Systems of Linear Equations word problem

Tags: linear-algebra

$95$ passengers rode in a train from City A to City B. Tickets for regular coach seats cost $\$115$. Tickets for sleeper cars cost $\$291$. The receipts for the trip totaled $\$20,429$. How many passengers purchased each type of ticket?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I did what i was "taught" to do, and made 2 equations, making 115 x and 291 y. Then I equaled those to 20429. For the second equation I did x+y=95. Its actually 95 passengers, not percent.

Comment: But everytime I think i have it right, i plug it in and its wrong

Answer (score 2):

Say $95$ passengers; $x$ of them pay for regular coach seats at $115$ USD an $y$ of them pay for sleeper cars at $291$ USD. So the equations are $$x+y=95$$ $$115x+291y=20429$$ You can eliminate $y$ from the first equation ($y=95-x$) and plug it into the second; this gives $$115x+291(95-x)=27645-176 x=20429$$ that is to say $x=41$ and then $y=54$.